# AttributeError: 'ZipInfo' object has no attribute 'filemode'

Tags: python, zip

How to access filemode attribute of zipfile?

```
>>> info = zin.infolist()[1]
>>> info
<ZipInfo filename='test_dir/' filemode='drwxr-xr-x' external_attr=0x10>
>>> info.filename
'test_dir/'
>>> info.external_attr
1106051088
>>> info.filemode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ZipInfo' object has no attribute 'filemode'
```

Comment: what is `filemode` supposed to contain? it doesn't exist under this name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file attributes are stored in the upper bits of `external_attr` (above the lower 16 bits):

```
oct(1106051088 >> 16)
#'0o40755'
```

To check specific permissions, use functions from the module [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stat.html), e.g.:

```
stat.S_ISDIR(1106051088 >> 16)
# True, a directory

stat.S_IRUSR & (1106051088>>16)
# 256, user-readable

stat.S_IWGRP&(1106051088>>16)
# 0, not group-writable
```